# rewrite wordpress url from archive date to a specific page

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to use the default archive calendar in wordpress to show a single page instead of the archive.

The default link is `blog/2015/04/13`, I would like it to point to `agenda/?dato=2015/04/13`.

I have tried my best and i currently stuck on the following and cannot figure out why it is not working.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/', 'agenda/?dato=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

EDIT:
As I could not get it to work I went in another direction and put the following in the archive.php of my theme.:

```
if(is_date()) {
$year     = get_query_var('year');
$monthnum = get_query_var('monthnum');
$day      = get_query_var('day');
$pagelink=get_page_link (get_page_by_title( 'AGENDA' )) . "?dato=" . $year . "/" . $monthnum . "/" . $day;
header("Location: $pagelink",TRUE,301);
}
```

That did the trick and is actually more useful if anybody needs it..

Comment: Your rewrite regex expects a trailing slash, but your example doesn't show one...

Comment: Try using `add_rewrite_rule('blog/([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})/?', 'agenda/?dato=$matches[1]', 'top');`. I have placed the round brackets around the match you are seeking, and added a `?` at the end to make `/` optional (since your input string has no slash at the end).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it doesn't seem to be working. Think it must be a wordpress thing.

Comment: try to add Priority in add_action for your init function, sometime other plugins get clash, the lowest the priority is better. as then it will get called at last and overwrite other plugins' effect if any. But for simplicity I too would go with your archive.php solution